# Integrity constraint violation when seeding

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i'm using laravel 5.4. A product belongs to one category, a category can a have many products. Each table has a uuid as primary key. 
I'm getting this error when seeding :

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`awesome`.`product`, CONSTRAINT `product_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`))
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugCq9.png)

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Here is the category model

```
class Category extends Base {
    protected $table = 'category';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name'];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Product');
    }
}
```

Here is the Product Model

```
class Product extends Base {
    protected $table = 'product';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
         ...,
        'category_id'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Category');
    }
}
```

the product migration

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->uuid('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the category migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the product factory

```
$factory->define(App\Model\Product::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => \Faker\Provider\Uuid::uuid(),
        'category_id' => function() {
            return factory(App\Model\Category::class)->create()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

the category factory

```
$factory->define(App\Model\Category::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => \Faker\Provider\Uuid::uuid(),
        'name' => $faker->word,
    ];
});
```

And the database seeder

```
public function run()
{
    factory(\App\Model\Category::class, 5)->create()->each (function ($category) {
       factory(\App\Model\Product::class, 5)->create(['category_id' => $category->id]);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i've understood what's happening. Because the name of the primary key is 'id' it's considered as an integer, and converted to an integer when i wrote $category->id, that gives 0. So there's no line in the Category table with 0 as id. Just have to change the name of the primary key.